# Redirect a domain to a subdirectory of another domain

Tags: redirect, dns, subdomain, hosting, blogs

I have a domain "first.com" and I have a blog on this domain "first.com/blog" (hosting in OVH)

I would like to create a redirection: "first.com/blog" to "blog.second.com" (hosting Heroku for rails app)

I think I have to configure OVH DNS to create this "redirection", but i don't know how.
Thx for helping.

Comment: You want to redirect based on a specific URL _path_, and that has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with the DNS. You need to let the request arrive at the server behind your first.com domain, and then redirect it from there.

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear, I want to display the content of the first.com/blog when i am on the url blog.second.com

Comment: Well then you want to set up the subdomain `blog.second.com` to point to your server behind first.com (yes, that part would be DNS), and then configure you server on first.com to handle requests for that subdomain, serving content out of the /first folder.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But I am not very familiar with this kind of hosting configurations, will you have an idea to do this?